# How do I create same username and password at phpBB forum as the username and password already saved

Tags: php, mysql, database, forum, phpbb

I have a site where all users need to sign up with username and password. Today I added the [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/) forum to my site. The problem is that users need to sign up for my site and the phpBB form separately. Can I just add to the phpbb_users db with php at the same time as they register for my site?

In that case I need to know what kind of password hash they are using in `user_password`, what this is: `user_email_hash, user_last_confirm_key, user_form_salt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use phpBB for authorization.

- How to log in to phpBB from your
  website (html code for login form): http://wiki.phpbb.com/display/MODDOCS/Practical.External+login
- How to check if user is logged in to phpBB: http://wiki.phpbb.com/display/MODDOCS/Practical.Add+custom+page

Hashing functions used in phpBB you can find in includes/functions.php file.